# On itemclick of recyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-textinputedittext

I tried to make an app in which I made a recycler View of Array List Of items and I want that when I will click on particular item of Array List the it should open a activity in which I could add some text with edit text and again if I want to open another item of Array List so it should open the same activity but not the previous saved data .

I want to add different data in each list of items. but its not happening for every list of items the same saved data is loading in the activity....

is there any solution..

this is second activity..

```
 protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.student_list);

    loadData();

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String subName = bundle.getString("Subject Name");

    if (bundle != null) {
        toolbar.setTitle(subName);
    }

    fabButton();
    buildRecyclerView();
}

private void buildRecyclerView() {

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView2);
    recyclerView.hasFixedSize();
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(StudentListActivity.this);
    rAdapter = new AdapterForStudentList(listOfNames);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(rAdapter);

    ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleCallback);
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

}

public void insertData(String text, String t1, String t2) {
    ListOfNames lt = new ListOfNames(text, t1, t2);
    listOfNames.add(lt);
    rAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

public void saveData() {
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SHARED PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(listOfNames);

    editor.putString("text", json);
    editor.apply();
}

public void loadData() {


    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SHARED PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sharedPreferences.getString("text", null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ListOfNames>>() {
    }.getType();

    listOfNames = gson.fromJson(json, type);

    if (listOfNames == null) {
        listOfNames = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}

ListOfNames deletedItem = null;
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
    @Override
    public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        final int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        String name = listOfNames.get(position).getStudentName();

        deletedItem = listOfNames.get(position);
        listOfNames.remove(deletedItem);

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SHARED PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.remove("text");


        saveData();
        editor.apply();
        rAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);

        Snackbar.make(recyclerView, name + "Deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Undo", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        listOfNames.add(position, deletedItem);
                        rAdapter.notifyItemInserted(position);

                        saveData();
                    }
                }).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildDrawOver(@NonNull Canvas c, @NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
        new RecyclerViewSwipeDecorator.Builder(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)

                .addSwipeLeftBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(StudentListActivity.this, R.color.my_background))
                .addSwipeLeftActionIcon(R.drawable.ic_delete_black_24dp)
                .create()
                .decorate();
        super.onChildDrawOver(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);

    }
};

public void fabButton() {
    FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fab2);
    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(StudentListActivity.this);
            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialogbox_frontpage, null);

            final EditText editText = view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
            b.setView(view);
            b.setTitle("Student name");
            b.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String text = editText.getText().toString();

                    if (text.isEmpty()) {
                        Toast.makeText(StudentListActivity.this, "Please add subject name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        insertData(text, t1, t2);
                        saveData();
                    }
                }
            });
            b.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            b.setCancelable(false);
            b.show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

```
**MainActivity**

`public class ScrollingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private AdaptreForRecycler adapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;
RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;


private Gson gson;
private String json;
private Type type;

private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


EditText editText;
private ExampleItem ex;
public static final String t2 = "new";



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    loadData();
    buildRecyclerView();

    editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    fabButoonClick();


}

public void saveData() {

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SHARED_PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    gson = new Gson();
    json = gson.toJson(mExampleList);

    editor.putString("text", json);
    editor.apply();

}

public void loadData() {

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SHARED_PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE);
    gson = new Gson();
    json = sharedPreferences.getString("text", null);
    type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ExampleItem>>() {
    }.getType();
    mExampleList = gson.fromJson(json, type);

    if (mExampleList == null) {
        mExampleList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

}


public void insertItem(String text, String t2) {

    ex = new ExampleItem(text, t2);
    mExampleList.add(ex);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


}

ExampleItem deletedIndex = null;
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
    @Override
    public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        final int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        String name = mExampleList.get(position).getText1();
        deletedIndex = (mExampleList.get(position));
        mExampleList.remove(position);

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SHARED_PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.remove("text");

        saveData();

        editor.apply();
        adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);

        Snackbar.make(recyclerView, name + " Deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Undo", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        mExampleList.add(position, deletedIndex);
                        adapter.notifyItemInserted(position);

                        saveData();

                    }
                }).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildDraw(@NonNull Canvas c, @NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {

        new RecyclerViewSwipeDecorator.Builder(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)

                .addSwipeLeftBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(ScrollingActivity.this, R.color.my_background))
                .addSwipeLeftActionIcon(R.drawable.ic_delete_black_24dp)
                .create()
                .decorate();
        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
    }
};


private void buildRecyclerView() {
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ScrollingActivity.this);
    adapter = new AdaptreForRecycler(mExampleList);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new AdaptreForRecycler.OnItemCLickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int position) {


            Intent i =new Intent(ScrollingActivity.this,StudentListActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("Subject Name",mExampleList.get(position).getText1());

            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleCallback);
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

public void fabButoonClick() {
    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(ScrollingActivity.this);
            View mview = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialogbox_frontpage, null);

            final EditText editText = mview.findViewById(R.id.editText);
            b.setView(mview);
            b.setTitle("Add subject name");
            b.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            b.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String text = editText.getText().toString();

                    if (text.isEmpty()) {
                        Toast.makeText(ScrollingActivity.this, "Please add subject name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {

                        insertItem(text, t2);

                        saveData();
                    }
                }
            });
            b.setCancelable(false);
            b.show();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_scrolling, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();


    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}AdaptreOfFirstActivity`

```
public class AdaptreForRecycler extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptreForRecycler.ProgrammingViewHolder> {

private OnItemCLickListener mListener;

public interface OnItemCLickListener {
    void onItemClick(int position);
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemCLickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;

public class ProgrammingViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView mTextView1, mTextView2;

    public ProgrammingViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, final OnItemCLickListener listener) {
        super(itemView);

        mTextView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        mTextView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv2);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (listener != null) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION)
                        listener.onItemClick(position);
                }
            }
        });

    }
}

public AdaptreForRecycler(ArrayList<ExampleItem> exampleList) {

    mExampleList = exampleList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public AdaptreForRecycler.ProgrammingViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_layout, parent, false);
    return new ProgrammingViewHolder(view, mListener);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdaptreForRecycler.ProgrammingViewHolder holder, int position) {

    ExampleItem currentItem = mExampleList.get(position);
    holder.mTextView1.setText(currentItem.getText1());
    holder.mTextView2.setText(currentItem.getText2());
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mExampleList.size();
}
```

}  `AdaptreForSecondActivity`

```
public class AdapterForStudentList extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterForStudentList.StudentViewHolder> {


private ArrayList<ListOfNames> mListOfNames;

public static class StudentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView studentName, attendence, percentage;

    public StudentViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        studentName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentName);
        attendence = itemView.findViewById(R.id.attendence);
        percentage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.percentage);


    }
}

public AdapterForStudentList(ArrayList<ListOfNames> listOfNames) {

    mListOfNames = listOfNames;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public StudentViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.check_box_cardview, parent, false);

    return new StudentViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull StudentViewHolder holder, int position) {

    ListOfNames currentItems = mListOfNames.get(position);
    holder.studentName.setText(currentItems.getStudentName());
    holder.attendence.setText(currentItems.getAttendent());
    holder.percentage.setText(currentItems.getPercetage());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mListOfNames.size();
}
```

}

Comment: can you post the code you already wrote ?

Comment: the code you added isn't enough to understand your problem ! please put the code of your two activities

Comment: i added it plz check is it enough...or what else i would have to put   Its not taking the full code to submit sry first time i m asking question in this website

Comment: put this class code studentListActivity.class to see what is doneplease

Comment: would i have to add whole class code

Comment: yes please to see what do you show as data

Comment: hey plz check the code now

Comment: sorry but u didn't post your second class code , when its shows always old data

Comment: For both the activity i have made a different adapter class should i put those also

Comment: In your  ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallBack you are removing the text before saving it.

Comment: And also i would suggest you use some kind of database SQLite or Firebase instead of SharedPrefences.

Comment: i m removing the text becz on every time when i will delete any data from list then it will remove the saved data from shared prefrences and again it will save the current data and load it when ever i will open my app....thats not the issue for me

Comment: i want to do with a simple method n i dont want to include databse n all isnt it possible

Comment: I have added all the classes now can u help @ismailalaoui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I saw that you did what I said in my first original answer, I compliment you for it.

Also, this thread/post can end here seeing that you already implemented the `onClick` for `RecyclerView`. I'd appreciate it if you mark my answer as the solution.

But of course, you raised another problem which is:

> **I want to add different data in each list of items. but its not
>   happening for every list of items the same saved data is loading in
>   the activity...**

That's because you're loading and also saving with the **same key**:

```
editor.putString("text", json);
editor.apply();
```

See there? You were loading and saving to the key `"text"` in each subject. (You mentioned that you have a list of subjects hence I used the word *subject*)

I suggest you create a means to change the key for each different subject. In this case, your subject's name can be the key instead of plain `"text"`.

I also suggest you to use a `private static final String` variable for `"text"` and also make it more clear. A key called `"text"` is a bit ambiguous don't you think?

Now I will post the modified code part of your `StudentListActivity`, I encourage you to analyse it and paste it to your code. I'm sure it will work now.

*Modified part in StudentListActivity*

```
// Added a string variable here as key for saving/loading your data
String subName; // I kept your naming the same which is 'subName'

protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.student_list);

    // I placed this bit of code above loadData() now that we
    // use subName as the key
    // Or else loadData() will use the initial value of
    // subName which is going to be null first
    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    subName = bundle.getString("Subject Name");

    if (bundle != null) {
        toolbar.setTitle(subName);setTitle(subName);
    }

    loadData();

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    fabButton();
    buildRecyclerView();
}

// Other code... Which in your code are:
// private void buildRecyclerView() { ... }
// public void insertData(String text, String t1, String t2) { ... }

public void saveData() {
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SHARED PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(listOfNames);

    // Now here use the name of your subject as key
    // Which is of course the variable 'subName'
    editor.putString(subName, json);
    editor.apply();
}

public void loadData() {


    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SHARED PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    // Same here
    // Use 'subName' as key
    String json = sharedPreferences.getString(subName, null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ListOfNames>>() {
    }.getType();

    listOfNames = gson.fromJson(json, type);

    if (listOfNames == null) {
        listOfNames = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}

// Other code ...
```

By the way, I tried making the layouts myself in order to test your application and I noticed something: I guess you have an `EditText` inside your `dialogbox_frontpage`.xml file. And you still wrote a code to get the view in to your `ScrollingActivity` which is unnecessary. In fact, you re-defined it inside the fab's `onClick` method. You can remove that `global` variable.

Last notes: This is just a suggestion but you could try and learn about the `Singleton` pattern. Use that pattern to save your data. 
Also, `SharedPreferences` is not really a good idea to save huge amount of data. So I also encourage you to try to look up [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) databases.

I hope your program works now and as always, happy coding! (This has been a very long answer, hahaha)

---

*Original answer (modified it a bit)*

I suggest to create an `interface` that will pass the position of the clicked item because we only care about the position of the item to be able to do something to it. Besides, it's better that way so that we can put in the activity the code to be executed when an item has been clicked.

This is how the `interface` should look like:

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int position);
}
```

Add a new `variable` inside your `adapter`, that is, the `OnItemClickListener`:

```
private OnItemCLickListener listener;
```

You could either define its implementation by implementing it to the activity or pass its implementation by creating another method called `addOnItemClickListener` in to your `adapter`:

```
addOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

Then inside your `onBindViewHolder` method, get the layout of the item from the `ViewHolder` and set its `onClick` listener and finally inside its `onClick` method, call your interface's method `onItemClick` inside it and pass the position there. Like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CustomRecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            listener.onItemClick(position);
        }
    });
}
```

---

**Edit: Explanation on why I set the listener inside the `onBindViewHolder` method**

The `itemView` or the `View` we get from the constructor of the `ViewHolder` **depends** on the `View` returned by the `LayoutInflater` inside your `onCreateViewHolder`. Hence, the layout resource you're passing in the `inflate` method, whatever the main layout you're using there (e.g. `ConstraintLayout`, `LinearLayout`, it can also be a `TextView`, `Button`, etc.), will be the `View` returned. To test this, try and copy/paste this simple line of code in your `onCreateViewHolder` then run your app and check `Logcat`:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT_HERE, parent, false);
    Log.i("View", view.getClass().getSimpleName()); // Logs the main view in our layout
    return new YourCustomViewHolderHere(view);
}
```

The `ViewHolder` is **only** responsible for getting our views because using the `findViewById` method is an extensive task if we do it inside `onBindViewHolder` so we don't do it there because it'll slow down the performance of our application.

We do all settings like changing the texts of the `TextViews` for example or setting `onClick` listeners *inside* the `onBindViewHolder` to avoid creating unnecessary complexity in our code. We don't want codes floating around now, would we?

Also, the Observer pattern is **quite dangerous**.

There was a talk in an Android Conference, I don't remember which, that talked about `RecyclerView`. Do you know why it's called like that? Because it *recycles* views. (It needs a proper explanation how they recycle views so I won't be covering it here. I think you can find it on YouTube if you search for *"Android Conference RecyclerView"*, it's quite long, maybe around an hour, but it's worth to watch it.)

The Observer pattern (i.e. Listener) may cause memory leaks in which will affect our application's performance. Hence, it's better to set it up inside our `onBindViewHolder` method because whenever we scroll down or up on our `RecyclerView`, it'll recycle views and we **risk** on creating *multiple* instances of the *same* listener inside the `ViewHolder`.

According to Wikipedia on [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern):

> The observer pattern can cause memory leaks, known as the lapsed
>   listener problem, because in basic implementation it requires both
>   explicit registration and explicit deregistration, as in the dispose
>   pattern, because the subject holds strong references to the observers,
>   keeping them alive. This can be prevented by the subject holding weak
>   references to the observers.

Another way to set an `onClick` is inside `onCreateViewHolder` but the catch is you don't have a way on knowing which item was clicked.

I hope this answers your question in the comment.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212946/discussion-on-answer-by--on-itemclick-of-recyclerview).